# Background repeat with scaling

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a view with a repeatable background drawable in Android (using "tileMode"), but since "gravity" is ignored when using tileMode, if the given drawable is not exactly the same pixel size of the view, it gets cropped or won't stretch to cover the whole view.

How do I make a repeatable background that scales accordingly to fill the view it is bound to? I find it very hard to believe that this is not supported, since it would make tileMode useless, especially in a world of variable dpi and screen sizes.